How to implement "IRefreshable" using the Instance property of the DynamicComponent
I am new to C# Blazor and I'm trying to develop a working project of the

Learn .NET ASP.NET Core - Dynamically-rendered ASP.NET Core Razor
components

Example. I don't get the IRefreshable interface implemented correctly. I seem to be missing some steps.
Please see my code snippets.
Class for details of dynamic components invoked:
public class DynamicInvokedComponentDetails 
{
     public required Type Component { get; set; }
     public DynamicComponent? ComponentRef { get; set; } = null;
     public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = [];
}

Parent component razor.cs (toolbar):
private string CurrentKey = string.Empty;

// Component data and parameters
private Dictionary<string, DynamicInvokedComponentDetails> Components => new()
 {
     [tradeDebtors] = new DynamicInvokedComponentDetails()
     {
         Component = typeof(TransactionCriteria),
         Parameters = []
     },
     [tradeCreditors] = new DynamicInvokedComponentDetails()
     {
         Component = typeof(TransactionCriteria),
         Parameters = []
     },
     [transfers] = new DynamicInvokedComponentDetails()
     {
         Component = typeof(TransactionCriteria),
         Parameters = []
     }
 };

private void OnToolBarButtonClick(string componentKey, SystemCategory systemCategory, TransactionCategory transactionCategory, MouseEventArgs Args)
{
    if (Components["componentKey"].ComponentRef != null)
    {
        CurrentKey = string.Empty;

        //**** Help required to implement this code
        //**** Statement not working - IRefreshable not correctly implemented ****
        //**** (Components["componentKey"].ComponentRef?.Instance as IRefreshable)?.Refresh();****
        return; 
    }
 
    CurrentKey = componentKey;
    Components["componentKey"].Parameters =
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["SystemCategory"] = systemCategory,
            ["TransactionCategory"] = transactionCategory
        };
}

Parent component .razor (toolbar):
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentKey))
{
      <DynamicComponent Type="@Components[CurrentKey].Component" 
                        Parameters="@Components[CurrentKey].Parameters" 
                        @ref="@Components[CurrentKey].ComponentRef" />
}

Child component .razor (display transaction details):
public void Refresh()
{
     _windowVisible = true;
     TransactionDetailWindowRef.Refresh();
     //    StateHasChanged();
}


Did you manage to reference IRefreshable?    DynamicComponent doesn't implement it, and I can find no reference to it in the DotNetCore source code.  The live Microsoft Documents document that plainly refers to it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-8.0.  I must be bind!   There is an IRefreshable in the Azure SDK, but that can't be it.

No, I have not managed the implementation, but I think that it requires a custom programed effort. "IRefreshable is an bold 'example interface provided by the developer' for the dynamic component instance."

See this issue I raised on Microsoft Documents about that bit of documentation - https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/33453
